# Can a big-endian xxhash be compared with a little-endian hash?

Tags: hash

I have a set of files that were hashed as xxhash64 (little endian) and stored in an .mhl file.

The same set of files were hashed by a separate program, as xxhash64be (big endian) and stored in a separate .mhl file.

I trust that the files' content was actually identical at the time of hashing, as I generated the MHL files one after the other.

First MHL file:

```
<hash>
    <file>SEB_3719.JPG</file>
    <size>6338411</size>
    <xxhash64>5a518dbf43939fe0</xxhash64>
    ...
</hash>
```

Second MHL file:

```
    <xxhash64be>e09f9343bf8d515a</xxhash64>
```

Can these two hashes be used to compare each other? Can they be converted or displayed in a different way?

Or would the original file be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 hashes are effectively identical. But one is serialized using little endian convention and the other uses big endian convention, therefore inverting the byte order. You can check, visually, that each pair of hexadecimal is identical, just in reverse order.

The official xxHash project recommends big endian convention, since it's the natural way to display a 64-bit number. It even offers a set of [canonical functions](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/35ff826d506c1611de37c9458415082b2c5d61fc/xxhash.h#L661) which guarantees that the byte representation will be identical on any machine, whatever its endianess.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed correct. `5a518dbf43939fe0` is in reverse order of `e09f9343bf8d515a`. I found some help for my implementation (in Python) at https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2m65dy/endianness_conversion_of_hex_values_in_python_2x/cm19qd2/

Comment: @Cyan could you please fix your github link to a permalink? It's off now as `dev` branch has moved. I can't tell which line you wanted highlighted but this link could be it. 


https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/35ff826d506c1611de37c9458415082b2c5d61fc/xxhash.h#L661

Comment: Yes, that's the correct reference.
Good point, let's update the link.